# How to generate the same AES key in Java(Android) as in .Net?

Tags: java, android, .net, encryption, aes

I need to generate an AES key in Java (Android) from salt and password given from .Net WebService. I need to have the same key as the key generated in .net with the same password and salt (using Rfc2898DeriveBytes and AesManaged()). 
Here is my code in Android:

```
char[] passwordAsCharArray = password.toCharArray();
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passwordAsCharArray, salt, 1000, 256); 
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
```

Here is code in .net:

```
byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key);
Rfc2898DeriveBytes derivedKey = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, keyBytes);
AesManaged rijndaelCSP = new AesManaged();
rijndaelCSP.BlockSize = 128;
rijndaelCSP.KeySize = 256;
rijndaelCSP.Key = derivedKey.GetBytes(rijndaelCSP.KeySize / 8);
rijndaelCSP.IV = derivedKey.GetBytes(rijndaelCSP.BlockSize / 8);                

ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijndaelCSP.CreateDecryptor();
```

When I compare both keys they are different. Any ideas how to generate on Android the same key as in .Net? (I know that the key which have been generated in .net is correct). 
Number of iterations in .Net is 1000, salt and password are also the same as in Android.

---

Ok, it turned out that I dont need exactly the same key (as a byte array). I needed this to decrypt a file (in Java) which have been encrypted in .Net - with this key it gaves me Bad Padding Exception so I think the key was different and that causes the problem, but all I needed to do was to generate IV like a key - that solved my problem. Thanks for response!

Comment: Just a question: You are passing (String, byte[]) to the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` constructor, but I couldn't find anywhere in [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhe81fz4.aspx) what the # of iterations is. Are you sure 1000 is the default value?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it by: derivedKey.IterationsCount - value is 1000

Comment: Could you show us the output of both code snippets in hexadecimals so we can make sure it is not an output encoding error? I don't think you need to wrap the output of `SecretKeyFactory.generateSecret()` into a `SecretKeySpec`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you used the "key" (which should be a password) as a salt in your .NET code, whereas the Java part uses a specified salt. Furthermore, you specified the Unicode character set for decoding your salt, which is weird, the salt should be a random octet string (== byte array) from the beginning.

I would recommend you transform your password and random salt to byte arrays first, compare both using a hexadecimal representation (on your console, or in your debugger) and only then use those as input parameters for the PBKDF2 function in each. I would recommend an UTF-8 encoding for your password.

Always specify all parameters in cryptography, try not to use default, e.g. for the iteration count. If your input is off by a single bit, the output will be completely incorrect, and there is no way to tell which parameter was responsible.

It looks like the Java and .NET PBKDF2 "primitive" is identical on both platforms, there is working code out on the internet.